# HTML Mockups Recomendation

Tags: software-development, html, web-development, css, display

The problem I'm trying to solve is we have a nontechnical person who deals with clients and they design a noninteractive mockup (it can be in word layout, sometimes rough design). 
Then we create a UI based on those requirements and then the person takes the screenshots and sends it to the client and then the client gets a better idea and again asks for changes/updates. Then again we have to update our UI configurations as most of these are web form-based UI. It wastes a lot of time.

Can I get some good suggestions for the tools for creating HTML mockups, which a non-technical person can also work on without wasting a lot of time to learn?
(I m thinking of creating and saving all the component for the web form and a non technical person can just reuse those).
Can u suggest a tool where I can easily achieve this?

Comment: I haven't used this in years, so I have no idea if it's still a decent tool, but I remember using Balsamiq for UI mockup: https://balsamiq.com/ (not adding this as an answer because this is not a very useful rec).

Comment: Maybe you can try [ Figma](http://figma.com) an online mockup tool

Comment: What operating system do you use, if you will accept a desktop solution. Also, please either add the [tag:gratis] tag, or state a budget. The more info that you give us, the more that we can help you.(good question, though. I am marking it as favo(u)rite :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you know https://www.invisionapp.com/

I've worked with some graphic designers who can not write code. You can upload images and create simple prototypes without knowledge of html or css.

When the prototypes were approved, the design was implemented by a developer.
This always worked well for us and the graphic designer didn't have to write a line of code but could create everything in a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

The Graphic Designers at my Company work with [Axure](https://www.axure.com/). It seems pretty easy to use and multiple people can work on one mock at once.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a website prototyping application.

There are a few out there. I recommend you look at them, download trial copies and test some. That really is the best way to decide which one fits your needs.

Here are a few:
https://www.invisionapp.com/

https://framer.com/

https://marvelapp.com/

https://origami.design/

https://proto.io/

https://www.justinmind.com/

https://draftium.com/

Also, if you or your team are familiar with Adobe products try Adobe XD. Good luck.